# Title CSS not working

Tags: css, class, hyperlink, title, tumblr

Here's my site: http://oldtimesdaily.tumblr.com/

On my index the titles of my posts are links, and the single post has not. But I want them to look the same so I added the class="Title" to both, but it only applies to the index page.

And here are the codes

CSS

```
.Post a.Title {
                    display:block;
                    line-height: 1.4;
                    color: #222;
                    margin-bottom:22px;
                    font-family:QuicksandBold, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    margin: 0px 25px 10px; /* Post Title */
                    font-weight: bold;
                    letter-spacing: 2px;
                    text-transform:uppercase;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    border-bottom:0px;
                    }
                    .Post a.Title:hover {
                        color: #300000 ;
                        }
                .Post.Single a.Title {
                    margin-bottom:11px;
                    }
```

And HTML

```
           <div class="Text">
                {block:Title}
                     {block:IndexPage}
                <a href="{Permalink}" target="_blank" class="Title">{Title}</a> 
                     {/block:IndexPage}
                     {block:PermalinkPage}
                 <span class="Title">{Title}</span>
                     {/block:PermalinkPage}
                {/block:Title}
```

Comment: (first letters of class and id should not be uppercase nor numbers, fixe it , else some browser wo'nt apply them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title is a span on single pages so `a.Title` does not apply.

You could fix it by changing `.Post a.Title` to `.Post a.Title, .Post span.Title`

Comment: Nothing else to say, it worked ) Thanks